# Layers of associations and descriptions on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to implement a resume feature and I was wondering the best practice for handling it. Lets assume a user has 2 pieces to a resume, education and work experience, and this is constant among all users. Then under each I want to save titles of things they've done (eg. Attended school at ______, worked at ________, project doing _______). Within these I want to save a description of that specific activity. What would be the best practice for implementing this?

So I need some association like: a user has_many experiences. An experience has_many titles. A title has_many descriptions. I also need to make the title of the experience is associated with the correct header (education or work experience).

I'm still pretty new to rails, and I'm sure there is a much easier and intuitive way to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you want an `Experience` model with `title` and `description` fields.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I was making it much to complicated. Would this allow me to have title with multiple descriptions. That is - title: "Worked at store". Then description1 is stocked shelves. Descriptions 2 is used cash register. Description 3 is trained new employees, etc.?

Comment: What do you think? Is there an unlimited number of possible descriptions? Then no, you would need an association. If the max is 3, you could just have description1, description2, and description3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these simple models structure for

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :locations
   has_many :projects, through: experience_projects
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end


class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  #experiences table should contain title and descriptions
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :projects, through: experience_projects
end
```

Now Join model if you do not require this intervention model you can directly use `has_and_belongs_to_many`

```
class ExperienceProject < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :experience
 end
```

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi, I think this may be exactly what I want. I'll think through it and try to implement it.